# Word highlighting in Qt using QRegExp

Tags: regex, qt, qstring, qregexp

I am trying to highlight a searched word using QRegExp.

This is the code.

```
QString text = "A <i>bon mot</i>.";
text.replace(QRegExp("<i>([^<]*)</i>"), "<b>\\1</b>");
//Output: "A <b>bon mot</b>."
```

The above code is working, but the below code is not working.

```
QString text1 = "This is a sample text.";
text1.replace(QRegExp("s"), "<b>\\1</b>");
//Output: "Thi<b>\1</b> i<b>\1</b> a <b>\1</b>ample text."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular expressions, `\1` corresponds to the first matched group.  Groups are parts of the regular expression in parentheses.  For example matching the string "hello world" against regexp `(hello)([.*])` will have `\1` corresponding to "hello" and `\2` to " world".

In your second snippet,

```
text1.replace(QRegExp("s"), "<b>\\1</b>");
```

you do not use parentheses, so there is no group `\1` would refer to.

Use

```
text1.replace(QRegExp("(s)"), "<b>\\1</b>");
```